# x86 machine code format for register indirect mode

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

The instruction format for x86 family which is shown below sounds ambiguous.

```
Fields:     opcode,direction,width     mod,reg,r/m
  Bits:        6      1         1       2   3   3
```

Assume the instruction is `MOV AX, [BP]`. No matter what is the opcode, we have the following numbers:

```
direction=1
    width=1
```

For the second byte, the `reg` is 000 (code for AX) and `mod` should be 00 but there is no entry for `bp` in the table. So, the `r/m` is unknown.

If we assume `mod` is 11 and `r/m` is 101, then that is the machine code for an instruction like `MOV AX, BP`.

Any idea?
[image]

Comment: `Mov ax,[bp]` is shortened for `Mov ax,[bp+0x00]`, mod is "01", and rm "110" ( for  (bp)+D8 )